# ssh connection refused on windows (wsl)

Tags: ssh, terminal

Stuck on error while starting a ssh server

**I already installed openssh-server and openssh-client**

Here is the image of error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The normal option to use when starting sshd would be:

- -D to test it (preventing it to detach its process and force it to run in foreground: try the ssh in a separate Windows)
- `-h host_key_file` if you are running it as a non-root user
- `-p port`, again if you are launching the daemon as a non-root user (and cannot use [privileged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)

If you can, in your WSL2 session, try

```
sudo sshd
```

That will run it as root, in the background

Then try your ssh command, making sure you have copied `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` first in `~zeus/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If that does not work, kill then run again sshd, this time with:

```
sudo sshd -d
```

That will launch it in foreground, and you will be able to see if your `ssh` command at least is received by the SSH server, and if there are any error messages.